# Creating asymetrical gradients

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, gradient

I've been curious for some time on how to create this asymetrical and multicolored gradient. I know how to do the multi color in photoshop/illustrator, but I am unsure how to create the asymetrical aspect of it.

[image]
[image]

My only other guess is that this is just a brush on multiple layers/colors that is then highly blended. If anyone knows how to create this in Adobe or Sketch it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is create massive circles of your chosen colors, as solids, and then apply VERY strong blurs to the image, as an effect, and move, scale and change colors of the underlying circles until you get the desired result.

Here's an example of doing this, taking the following...

[image]

and blurring it, heavily, creates this: [cropped, see blurred line on left, I was THAT lazy]

[image]

Comment: This is the better answer as it doesn't require an external source.  I will up vote this if you include examples of the blur settings you used.

Comment: Thanks for both responses! I was thinking there were probably a few ways to go about it, I'll play around with both. Thanks again!

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ blur settings are incomprehensible without size of image, and distracting. It's a very strong blur, and the range that's acceptable is entirely up to taste, and dependent on the manner in which the circles are drawn. It was very deliberately left vague for all three of these reasons.

Comment: Further, @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ, the type of blurs used and the software used all impact the outcome... but, most weirdly, if you try it yourself, you'll find the range of acceptable results is ENORMOUS!

Comment: well that is where I would take a stab at creating two answers, one for photoshop and one for gimp.

Comment: But, most importantly, for me, I don't want to reveal which app I did this in, because I don't actually believe it's a good app. I would like to encourage people to realise this is possible in any app, to their taste, the way they want, so long as they blur, a LOT!

Answer (score 2):

These can be done using a Gradient Mesh in Illustrator, and there will be lots of videos/etc on this feature online: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html or https://youtu.be/ZuYkybDBr-I?t=195